# Unresolved class '{applicationName}' in android manifest file

Tags: flutter, class, manifest

Android Manifest multiple errors

[image]

I have no clue what to do here.

Comment: Right click on android folder -> flutter -> open Android module in Android studio.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem i deleted that line

```
android:name="${applicationName}"
```

and it solved my problem.